# Accessing PHP variables in HTML page

Tags: php

I am trying to display an error message inside a `<span>` tag, but I am getting an error saying

> Notice: Undefined variable: user_name_error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\same_page.php on line 128

Below is a sample of how my code look like.

**same_page.php**

```
<?php

 $user_name_error= "some_error_to_display";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

....
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
                <span id="check-e"><?php echo $user_name_error; ?></span>
            </div>
.....
</html>
```

I have tried using `$GLOBALS['user_name_error']= 'error_msg'` and `<?php echo "$user_name_error"` but in never worked.Any ideas?

Comment: `$user_name_error` must not be in scope of the page you are on. What are the `...`s?

Comment: Can you paste the whole content of same_page.php at http://pastebin.com/ and give us the link?

Comment: @chris85 The `....` is the rest of the code.

Comment: @DilipRajBaral I will do so , Thanks

Comment: Yea, I meant literally what is the other code. Are you using functions?

Comment: @chris85- Nop, I am not using functions only `if...else` statements

Comment: @DilipRajBaral-Here is the link http://pastebin.com/UC9JYN5Z

Comment: It may not be helpful, but I noticed two `;` on your `$_GLOBAL` line, and `<?=$bank_error;?>` instead of starting with `<?php`

Comment: @mickmackusa-Thank you,I have rectified that but unfortunately, errors still persist

Comment: Typo @ Line 33 `$GOLBALS`

Comment: @mickmackusa-Thanks for pointing out, I guess I was a bit frustrated about the whole code throwing errors which I cant figure out how to solve.Still it's ain't working I will keep on trying to make it work.

Comment: More typos to correct: replace all occurrences of `passowrd` with `password`.  Remove spaces between `else if`, it should be `elseif` in php.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am on it!:-) will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

After pulling my hair for sometime I was able to fix the problem and I hope it will be helpful to someone.I used the function `isset()` to check if the variable is set and display the error otherwise there is no error message to display.

```
<span id="check-e"><?php if(isset($user_name_error)){echo "$user_name_error";}  else echo ""; ?></span>
```

Comment: If you don't want to muddy up your html section, on line 35, add `else{ $_GLOBALS['user_name_error']="";}` so that the variable is declared even if `$user_name` is valid.